# How do I change the title and link colors of a Google Custom Search Element?

Tags: search, element, google-custom-search

### The situation:

Take a look at this page and search "photo" on both:
http://dev.womenandlogistics.com/testsearchengine.html

The top search engine refreshes the page and displays results with orange link titles and blue links. The bottom search engine displays tabbed results with blue link titles and blue links.

I found an answer to this on the Google forums; however, I am inexperienced with AJAX so I have no idea what to do this answer. I've read through various Google documentations on custom search engines and web elements regarding this, but I still can't figure it out.

### What I've tried so far...

- Added a class in the  section (class="gsc-result gsc-webResult") and added the corresponding CSS (#gsc-result gsc-webResult) on the page to see if that works, but it didn't.
- Viewed the context XML file to see if I can make changes. This only affects the top search box.

### What you can do to help

- Provide an explanation of what I'm doing wrong
- Provide an explanation of where I should be looking
- Show me samples of code that illustrates the actual color changes and where it can be found

I really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: Would help if the link worked

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I suggest

1. Go to this link https://www.google.com/cse/ and create account
2. Create your custom search box
3. Customize looks as your wish
4. Copy the code after customizing
5. Paste in your blog or website where you want the search box to appear

Source: http://www.latestgames2.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://spryserif.com/testsearchengine.html